# Merge this if statement with the enclosing one in sonar

Tags: java, sonarlint

Why Sonar showing below code having Major issue and its saying Marge this if statement with enclosing one

If i do that there will be functional issue will come .How can i solve this problem

### code

```
    if (Optional.ofNullable(baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass()).isPresent()) {
            if (!baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("High")
                    && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Low")
                    && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Medium")
                    && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Unknown")) {
                errors.add(new Error("EPO_CATALOG_ERR_04", "Invalid Credit Class in the Request."));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your structure is basically the following: `if (A) { if (B) { statement(); } }`. That can be equivalently written as `if (A && B) { statement(); }`!

Comment: Side note: Why `if (Optional.ofNullable(baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass()).isPresent())` instead of the simpler `if (baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass() != null)`?

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the assertion that combining if statements makes code more readable is flawed. Often it makes sense to ask a series of questions in sequence, especially when each part is asking an essentially independent question.

This can (in direct opposition of the SonarQube assertion) make each part *more* readable. It also allows for correct placement of useful comments in cases where the meaning is not stupidly obvious.

Another valid reason for nested if statements would be to follow certain easily recognized coding patterns. An example would be in ASP.Net applications where Page_Load methods may often have an if (!PostBack) block, which can then contain additional logic that may include additional nested conditions. If there is only one nested condition and it is combined, later changes may need to undo that merge. (There may be a case at that point for refactoring the logic into a separate method at that point, but that is a different subject.)

The question of whether or not to combine nested if statements should be left to the discretion and good judgement of the author (and code reviewer) based on which form is more readable and/or maintainable.

So yes, the suggested change would not change functionality, but is not necessarily better.

Answer (score 0):

What Sonar is suggesting here is to do something like this:

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass()).isPresent()) && (!baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("High")
                && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Low")
                && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Medium")
                && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Unknown")) {
            errors.add(new Error("EPO_CATALOG_ERR_04", "Invalid Credit Class in the Request."));

}
```

No functional issue here, as it does the same without an extra if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an else case for the if inside the isPresent() loop, it wouldn't throw such an error. As there is only one case inside that isPresent() loop, it is suggesting you to add that single condition check in one if loop.

I think it is suggesting you to write in this way according to the code you have written:

```
 if (Optional.ofNullable(baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass()).isPresent()
            && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("High")
                    && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Low")
                    && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Medium")
                    && !baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Unknown")) {
                errors.add(new Error("EPO_CATALOG_ERR_04", "Invalid Credit Class in the Request."));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a variable and check it inside one if statement :

```
String creditClass = baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass();
if (Optional.ofNullable(creditClass ).isPresent()) &&
        !creditClass.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("High")
        ...
```

Or even remove null check

```
String optionalCreditClass = baseOffersRequest.getCreditClass();
String creditClass =optionalCreditClass == null ? "" : optionalCreditClass.trim();
if (!"High".equalsIgnoreCase(creditClass) && 
...
```